In my Selenium project I am getting ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
I'm working on a selenium project. I'm trying to log in to a site. I can log in easily using normal methods, but when I run the code and send a login request, I get ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR. I couldn't figure out what should I do?
I added selenium libraries by creating a junit test project. I have coded the steps to be done normally in my project. When I run the code, the first stages run smoothly. However, when I enter the e-mail address and send a request to proceed to the next stage, I receive this error.
You can watch the problem I am experiencing in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tQDaiFv1DGI
Note: This problem only occurs when using selenium web driver. There is no such problem in normal use.
Is security against these bots important?
I did some research and couldn't come to a conclusion.
I reset Cashe settings.
I updated the driver to the latest version.
I disabled the http 2 method, but this time I couldn't send the request at all.
I am sharing my Junit code:
// Generated by Selenium IDE
package com.example.test;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.After;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsNot.not;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.util.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


public class LoginTest {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private Map<String, Object> vars;
  JavascriptExecutor js;
  @Before
  public void setUp() {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");

//      options.addArguments("--disable-http2");
      options.addArguments("--no-cache");
//      options.addArguments("--no-store");
//      options.addArguments("--must-revalidate");
      //options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.EAGER);

//      options.addArguments("--aggressive-cache-discard") ;

    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  }
  @After
  public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
  }

  @Test
  public void login() {

    driver.get("https://www.sephora.com.tr/giris-yap");

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

   driver.findElement(By.id("footer_tc_privacy_button_2")).click();

    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    driver.findElement(By.id("dwfrm_crmsephoracard_email")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.id("dwfrm_crmsephoracard_email")).sendKeys("lmnfnrbhc@gmail.com");


      WebElement emailInput = driver.findElement(By.id("dwfrm_crmsephoracard_email"));

//    try {
//      Thread.sleep(10000);
//    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//      e.printStackTrace();
//    }


      emailInput.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

      try {
          Thread.sleep(1000000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

    driver.findElement(By.className("field-wrapper has-input")).sendKeys("MyPassword");

    try {
      Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    driver.findElement(By.id("field-wrapper has-input")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);


  }
}


Hi. Welcome to stackoverflow. Please check [ask] and [edit] your question... don't expect anybody to watch a video. Explain in the question what you are trying to do. Clean up your code to make it a [mcve]; remove all the extra stuff, so that people can just copy & paste your code and reproduce the same issue you are seeing. Unrelated: Don't swallow exceptions; when something in your test fails, you just try to continue, and that is unlikely to work and make debugging harder.
